# Confidence Interval for Centered Moving Average of Autocorrelated Timeseries Data (Smoothing)

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, autocorrelation, smoothing, moving-average

I want to compute the confidence intervals of moving average (MA) which I apply to a time series with both high-frequency and low-frequency terms.

I'm interested in the slowly changing part only (trend estimation) and therefore apply a MA as sort of a low-pass filter.

There exists already an [answer in case of uncorrelated data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/524673/confidence-interval-for-centered-moving-average-of-timeseries-data-smoothing). However, in my case, the time series is highly auto-correlated and the answer provided in the linked thread is not valid.

**How can one calculate the confidence interval of a moving average where the generating process is known to be auto-correlated?**